# Manually changing the style of disabled ListViewItem

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a `ListView` in my metro app with some disabled items which are grayed out. I wanted to change the style of this items to the default style of enabled items, but the items still need to be disabled. I think that it would have the same effect if I only had to somehow skip the graying out of disabled items and I dont know how to do that, so please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the style of your `ListViewItem`. The simplest way to do this is to right click on a `ListViewItem` in the designer and select `Edit Template` > `Edit a Copy...`:

[image]

The next step is naming the new style and selecting where it should be put:

[image]

Inside the style find the following block:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
    <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{StaticResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

You can delete it or comment it out to prevent the items from being grayed out. Of course you can also change the style of `Disabled` visual state in whatever way you desire.